# Flutter java.io.File android.app.Activity.getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, flutter, background-service

After I install the `android_alarm_manager` on my project I got this error..

```
I/AlarmService(24713): Starting AlarmService...
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.app.Activity.getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(ImagePickerPlugin.java:27)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:29)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at com.example.myapp.Application.registerWith(Application.java:18)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService.startAlarmService(AlarmService.java:65)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.startService(AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.java:75)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.onMethodCall(AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.java:52)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:191)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:163)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_alarm_manager(24713):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:708)                                      4.8s
  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Mi 4i is available at: http://127.0.0.1:3860/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
E/flutter (24713): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (24713): PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.app.Activity.getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter (24713): #0      JSONMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:149:7)
E/flutter (24713): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter (24713): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24713): #2      AndroidAlarmManager.initialize (package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart:70:10)
E/flutter (24713): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  dio: "^1.0.1"
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  local_auth: "^0.2.0"
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.0"
  http: "^0.11.3+16"
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  image_picker: "^0.4.10"
  multi_image_picker: "1.0.51"
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.1.3
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.1.5
  connectivity: ^0.3.1
  sqflite : any
  location: ^1.4.1
  android_alarm_manager: ^0.2.1
  geolocator: '^1.7.0'
```

My `main.dart`

```
void main() async {
  final int msgId = 0;
  runApp(new LoginApp());
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 5), msgId, autoResendReports);
}

void autoResendReports() {
  print("TEST");
  final DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print(
      "[$now] Hello, world! isolate=$isolateId function='$autoResendReports'");
}

class LoginApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

My AndroidManifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I still can't make the background service for flutter work. Please help.

Comment: can you post your manifest file?

Comment: @oliver I updated my question.

Comment: Hi. did you manage to solve this problem? having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in similar issue for a while, so I tried to work around using the java file. So, basically what I am doing is that I have created the background logic I want using java in the android side, which is easy to do. Then I talk with that side from flutter using MethodChannel. My app is simply need to run an alarm when the app timer finish counting even if in background. I still have some issues in variable passing to the service in android side, which is minor I think, but in general the background thing worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. We appreciate your participation. But I don't think your answer help the OP at all. If you think you did something different then paste the code block or the exact steps you took.